# Unable to use select option value in form for new window in JavaScript correctly

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select

I'm a newbie with JavaScript and I asked a question earlier and got answers which helped me, but I thought I could incorporate it into the larger form I was working with and now I'm stuck again.

I have a large form with one select option. When the form is filled out, a new window opens and incorporates the values submitted into an invitation type page.

Everything else is working except for this select option. The problem I am having is depending on the selection, I want different text to be written into the new window (as part of the overall new window invitation page).

I'm really close, mostly b/c of help I received earlier today -- I can either get the new window to show just my named option value or I can get a whole new window with the different text (that is not part of the invitation page). I just can't combine the two.

I wrote up a smaller page in case someone wants to take a look at it. Thanks in advance.

```
 <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>JavaScript Forms</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
   <script type="text/JavaScript">

function newWindow() {
    allInfo = open("", "displayWindow");

    allInfo.document.open();

    allInfo.document.write('<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle_invite.css"><title>Resume</title><meta charset="utf-8"> </head><body>');
    allInfo.document.write(document.getElementById ('firstname').value);
    allInfo.document.write('</body></html>');

    allInfo.document.close();

}

function showName() {

    var doIt=document.getElementById('firstname').value;

    if ( doIt == "Michael" ) {
        allInfo.document.write("Mr. " + doIt); //only "Mikey" is written out
    }                                        
    else if ( doIt == "Sam" ) {
        allInfo.document.write("Mrs. " + doIt);
    }
    else   {
        allInfo.document.write("Sir " + doIt);
    }
}
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
   <script type="text/JavaScript">
   </script>

      <form id="infoForm" method="post" name="infoForm">

        <p>First Name:</p>
       <p><select id="firstname" onChange="showName()" >
          <option value="Mikey">nickname1</option>
          <option value="Sammy">nickname2</option>
          <option value="Sir Doug">nickname3</option>
        </select></p>

      <p> <input type="button" value="Submit Information" onClick="newWindow()"></p>
    </form>

    </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: when are you calling the function showName()?

Comment: @JustinT.Watts It's on `<select id="firstname" onChange="showName()">`

Comment: `showName()` is writing after the `</html>`, so it isn't visible. Only things between `<body>` and `</body>` are rendered in the window.

Comment: at onChange -- if I call it at onClick it just opens a new window (with the correct text added to it) but it is not embedded(parsed?) into the newWindow I have already made.

Comment: Looks like you're calling showName() before the allInfo window is created. You need to store the value in somewhere else and should be read when allInfo window is opened.

Comment: Barmar, so do I add showName to the allInfo.document write in the newWindow functio? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Values in the *if* statements don't match those in the option elements, e.g. `if ( doIt == "Michael" )` vs `<option value="Mikey">`.

Comment: @Mike—concatenate all the text into one value, then write it using one *document.write* statement. There is no need for *document.open*, *document.write* calls that if required (keep *document.close*).

Comment: RobG, that's true. I kind of mixed some stuff up when I was making my smaller example page. It should read if (doIt = "Mikey" ) etc., but either way, it is ignoring that and just writing either Mikey, Sammy, or Sir Doug.

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings that can help a lot here. First opening a second window can be a painful experience both for the user and the programmer. Unless you have an absolute need I would recommend manipulating the current window's DOM to display a popup instead.

Next if you can use DOM methods to change the page contents. `document.write` comes with a lot of problems which in your case are not apparent. Mainly it can erase you current DOM. You don't notice this in your example because the new window is blank so rewriting it is incidental.

Finally your use of `allInfo` is a quirky way to reference a global variable. It is not easily understood that this is happening from the style of code. In fact any linter will throw an error for your use of the global and will case an error if you declare `"use strict"` in your functions. Best to learn the good coding practises way.

Since we will want to interact with a variable (`allInfo`) in your case we should encapsulate the value in an object. This object can hold the state of that reference and offer some abstracted interactions with it. By doing so you avoid polluting the global name space and allow you to swap out your implementation without having to rewrite the parts of your program that depend on it.

```
// Our welcome window object
function WelcomeWindow() {
  // save a reference to the content of your new window
  // to be printed when ready. (Lazy execution)
  this.innerHTML = '';
}
WelcomeWindow.prototype.open = function() {
  this.win = window.open("", "displayWindow");
  return this;
};
WelcomeWindow.prototype.close = function() {
  this.win.close();
  return this;
};
WelcomeWindow.prototype.write = function(html) {
  this.innerHTML += '' + html;
  return this;
};
WelcomeWindow.prototype.render = function() {
  if (!this.win) { throw new Error("window has not been opened yet."); }
  this.win.open();
  this.win.write('<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle_invite.css"><title>Resume</title><meta charset="utf-8"> </head><body>');
  this.win.write(this.innerHTML);
  this.win.write('</body></html>');
  this.win.close();
  return this;
};
```

This allows us to declaratively manipulate the window before it is opened. For example if we want to add the name to the window:

```
function NameField(id) {
  this.element = document.getElementById(id);
}
NameField.prototype.toString = function() {
  var name = this.element.value;
  switch (name) {
    case 'Michael': return 'Mr. Michael';
    case 'Sam':     return 'Mrs. Sam';
    default:        return 'Sir ' + name;
  }
};
NameField.prototype.toHtml = function() {
  return '<strong>' + this.toString() + '</strong>';
};
```

Linking it together using code instead because adding events into the DOM only confuses the separation of markup and code.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('infoForm');
  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = new NameField('firstName');
    new WelcomWindow()
      .write(name.toHtml())
      .open()
      .render();
    return false;
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation, but since I am just learning JavaScript, I wouldn't feel right using code like this that I don't yet understand. I actually figured it out. I don't know if it is correct or not, but it works -- Chrome console showed no errors, and it validated as correct HTML. I just added the text I wanted to write to the correct new window to the option value under the select element. I got rid of the showName function and the onChange event. I guess I was able to do it with the html and JavaScript I already had. Wish I could've figured it out with the function I made.

Comment: I know of no better way to learn good programming practices and increase your knowledge and experience then by example. That is why I showed what I did. I would instead learn from good quality code then to continue justifying poor quality code.

Comment: I agree, and I will look at it closely and try to figure it out. Thanks again.